# Как сделать роутинг при помощи массива объектов?(react-router-dom)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, маршрутизация, react-router-dom

Всем привет. Не так давно я смотрел видео про то, как пользоваться firestore используя react(вот ссылка, если кому интересно: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=12kgyxvsxUs&t=581s). Там я увидел клевый вариант роутинга при помощи массива объектов. Смысл в том, что есть два массива: публичные и приватные роуты. А в этих массивах находятся объекты со свойствами: path и component. Потом мы создаем компонент, который берет один из таких массивов и при помощи map делает из него массив роутов, а в конце мы прибавляем редирект для несуществующих путей. Вот примерно то, как это выглядит:

```
export const publicRoutes = [
    {
        path: HOME_ROUTE,
        component: Home,
    },
    {
        path: LOGIN_ROUTE,
        component: Login,
    }
];

export const privateRoutes = [
    {
        path: PROFILE_ROUTE,
        component: Profile,
    }
]; 

const AppRouter = ({routesArr, redirectPath = '/'}) => {
    return (
        <Switch>
            {routesArr.map(({path, component}) =>
                <Route key={path} path={path} component={component} exact={true}/>
            )}
            <Redirect to={redirectPath}/>
        </Switch>
    );
};
```

Проблема же состоит в том, что в видео автор использует публичные пути, когда пользователь только не авторизован, если пользователь авторизуется, то он использует только приватные роуты. Я же хочу сделать так, чтобы публичные роуты были доступны в любом из этих случаев. Но из-за редиректов получается так, что я не могу это сделать. Т.к. если я вставляю компонент с публичными роутами всегда и хочу зайти на какую-то приватную страницу сайта будучи авторизованным, то при рендере все равно срабатывает редирект публичных роутов и просто не дает мне этого сделать. Аналогичная ситуация происходит, если я меняю местами компоненты с публичными и приватными роутами.

```
const App = () => {
    let [isAuth, setIsAuth] = useState(false);

    return (
        <BrowserRouter>
            isAuth: {isAuth ? 'true': 'false'}
            <button onClick={() => setIsAuth(!isAuth)}>change isAuth</button>
            <Header/>
            <AppRouter routesArr={publicRoutes}/>
            {isAuth && <AppRouter routesArr={privateRoutes} redirectPath={PROFILE_ROUTE}/>}
        </BrowserRouter>
    );
}
```

Возможно, кто-то знает, как реализовать примерно такую же функциональность, не вставляя в код кучу костылей?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всем снова привет) В общем, я тут еще немного подумал и кое-что придумал. Теперь у нас есть не массивы с публичными и приватными роутами, а один амссив со всеми роутами. Но только теперь эти роуты в массиве можно настраивать) Я добавил свойство withAuth, которое как раз и отвечает за то, будет ли этот путь приватным или нет. Так же я написал hoc, которая принимает другую компоненту и проверяет, авторизован пользователь или нет. Вот код реализации:

```
export const appRoutes = [
    {
        path: HOME_ROUTE,
        Component: Home,
        exact: true,
    },
    {
        path: LOGIN_ROUTE,
        Component: Login,
    },
    {
        path: PROFILE_ROUTE,
        Component: Profile,
        withAuth: true,
    }
]; 

    const AppRouter = () => {
        return (
            <Switch>
                {appRoutes.map(({path, Component, exact, withAuth}) => {
                    if (withAuth) {
                        return <Route path={path} exact={exact} component={withAuthRedirect(Component)}/>
                    }
    
                    return <Route path={path} exact={exact} component={Component}/>
                })}
                <Redirect to={HOME_ROUTE}/>
            </Switch>
        );
    };

const App = ({isAuth, login_user, logout_user}) => {

    return (
        <BrowserRouter>
            isAuth: {isAuth ? 'true': 'false'}
            <button onClick={login_user}>login</button>
            <button onClick={logout_user}>logout</button>
            <div>
                <NavLink to={PROFILE_ROUTE}>Profile</NavLink>
            </div>
            <Header/>
            <AppRouter />
        </BrowserRouter>
    );
}
```

Единственное, у меня немного вызывает сомнение мой вызов withAuthRedirect, корректно ли так делать?